# Rails, google maps for rails(gmaps4rails) - marker list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

Is it possible to make marker list with gmaps4rails similiar to google maps?

I want to make something like that:

http://maps.google.pl/maps?hl=pl&biw=1280&bih=658&q=pharmacy&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=462l1804l0l2192l8l7l0l0l0l0l266l1104l0.4.2l6l0&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&tab=wl

I have found option to declare list:

https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Markers

But I don't know how to add to each marker upcase character(ie A, B, C).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It cannot be direct. You should:

- Create a mapping between your set of objects and a letter (one id => one letter).
- use this mapping to create the proper text in the list
- import a list of markers with letters and pick the right one according to your mapping

---

Edit:

In your model:

```
 attr_accessor :number

 def gmaps4rails_sidebar
   "#{number}: whatever text you need"
 end

 def gmaps4rails_marker_picture
   # set picture depending on number
 end
```

In your controller:

```
 @users = User.all
 @users.each_with_index do |user,index|
   user.number = index
 end
 @json = @users.to_gmaps4rails
```

Comment: How to add letter to marker? There is some info in FAQ? I didn't notice that.

Comment: You have to import custom markers and copy the pics in your public directory. I don't provide this

Comment: I gave an example with number, it's quicker. The shift to letters is only more lines of code. You have all the logic here.